# What is the optimized regex to match the email pattern in java

Tags: java, regex, email, pattern-matching

I am using the below regex in my program for matching the email pattern which is working fine.
Pattern :

```
(?i)[a-z0-9!#$%&amp;*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&amp;'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])+
```

It matching all the emails correctly. 
But now my use case is to apply above email regex for content which contains very large junk values. Ex: 30K continues alphanumeric characters without any empty space. In such cases, code take more very long time to process. Ex : **more than a minutes**, where normal content (without such junk content)  takes **less than a second**.

Couple of clarifications:

1. Why system taking long time while matching above regex for large
   junk characters
2. What would be the optimized regex to overcome the
   delay

Comment: Well, normal content does not have 30k characters. That's why its faster...

Comment: Can you make some quantifier [possessive](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html)?

Comment: your regex has some odd pieces like `&amp;` within a character group. And the combination of (something)*(something)+ results in lots of potential for backtracking - you can try https://regex101.com/ 's regex debugger to see that

Answer (score 0):

Not with regex.

1. Find character '@' at line

   int at = str.indexOf('@');
   if(i == -1)
     return;
   String address = str.substring(0, at - 1);
2. Find domain

   if(str.substring(at).indexOf('.') == -1)
   return;
   String domain = str.substring(at + 1)
3. Validate for incorrect symbols
4. Validate (send SMTP to server)